# Why did my computer's ubuntu installation screw up after fixing not being able to login because of no disk space left(100% used up)?

Tags: installation, login, kde, kwin

Seriously, I want to see some answers on this question, so if you will, please refrain from not answering this question if you know(or think you know) what went on with my computer. I'm tired of seeing my questions go unanswered.

I was using my computer as I normally do, when my computer(Ubuntu + KDE) notified me that I was running low on available disk space(since my linux install is only 30 GB). Because of the message, I was going to go through my installed programs/games/files a bit later to get rid of anything that I have on my Ubuntu install that I don't use or can do without.

I was doing some system setting changes, changing my splash screen and decided to restart my computer. upon returning to the login screen(KDM), it informed me that basically there was not enough free space to log me in to my Ubuntu installation on my computer. I thought to myself "WTF?!?!?". So basically, my first thought was to grab my copy of Puppy Linux that I already had on a Live CD, pop it into my computer and go through any pictures/music/downloads that I had on my computer I don't really need or can easily get back(from another drive I have), then go back and see if doing that was enough to be able to log in. Sure enough it was and I was able to log in.

So then as I logged in and this is where I started experiencing odd problems with KDE.

First off, I had no window decorations/borders(window title bar with the minimize, maximize, close buttons), unable to type anything within the terminal(keyboard not working with he terminal), and most of the time couldn't type anything in the search box in the kickoff application launcher.

Luckily, I had Cairo Dock which I was extremely fortunate that I was able to use my keyboard with it's terminal. My fist thought of why I had no window decorations/borders/title bar was because kwin was simply not running and needed to be restarted. So naturally I typed into to Cairo Dock's terminal "kwin --replace", it informed me that "The program 'kwin' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install kde-window-manager". First off I was completely and utterly puzzled as to why it said that kwin wasn't installed. How?!?!? How could it not be installed when it came with KDE and I have never uninstalled it! So after typing in the command to install kwin, everything is back to it was before I was experiencing this problem. I later uninstalled some games in wine that I no longer needed to have installed in Ubuntu(because I have them on my Windows installation) and freed up more disk space.

SO here are my questions:

1. How can I set up Ubuntu with KDE(or Ubuntu in general if desktop environments don't matter in this case) so that my computer will never run "low enough" on disk space that I will be unable to login?
2. Why was I unable to use my keyboard with KDE's terminal?
3. How on earth did kwin get uninstalled from my KDE installation when I did absolutely nothing to the installation of kwin that came with KDE by default?

Answer (score 1):

As I do not have enough information to write a comment, I am forced to write an answer.

First of all, I see what you mean and often ran in the situation of having no space left, especially if experiment with small installs. 
I noticed different issues, but none of the issues 2. or 3. 
In case of KDE Plasma for example suddenly all my desktop widgets were gone when I removed files in order to free space (and no, I did not remove the config files).

For explaining a few factors it would be important to know:

1. what filesystem you were using
2. if you were using prelink (which can corrupt binaries in case of low space left)

To your first question: You could setup a root and a home partition, which does not solve the issue, but at least makes sure that nothing unexpected happens to the root partition if home is full.

In case you cannot login anymore: You do not need another live cd: Just log-in in a virtual terminal: (By pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1) and make space free.

I think the warnings of too less space available are there for some reason. You cannot simply restrict disk space so that still for example 3 MB would be free but not writable. What difference would the latter make? You cannot write it anymore anyway, which is required by X to log in as user.

Comment: As for answering your two questions: 1. I really don't know what file system I am using. I assume I was using either ubuntu's default or the one that KDE uses by default after installing "kde-plasma-desktop"(the kde desktop enviornment). 2. I have no clue what prelink is but I'm going to assume I wasn't using it.